# angular js project not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web

i am working on a small project with angular js(ps:this is the first time i'm using it )and i'm blocked by this error and i don't understand why

```
angular.module("jsonerator", [])
.controller('theController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.personld = {
        "@context": {
            "schema": "http://schema.org/"
        },
        "@graph": [
            {
                "@id": "person",
                "@type": "schema:Person",
            }
        ]
    }

    $scope.personld["@graph"][0]["schema:givenName"] = "";
    $scope.personld["@graph"][1]["schema:familyName"] = "";
}
```

Comment: *"blocked by this error"*.. what error?

Comment: oh sorry0thsi one:"Cannot set property 'schema:familyName' of undefined"

Comment: You have only one element in array `"@graph"`. So `$scope.personld["@graph"][1]` is indeed undefined. You probably want `$scope.personld["@graph"][0]["schema:familyName"] = ""`

Comment: that is because there is only one item in the array and you are calling ```$scope.personld["@graph"][1]["schema:familyName"] = "";``` referencing ['@graph'][1]``` --- ```[1]``` does not exist

Comment: so how can i solve it?

Comment: @user3430205 you understand why that wasn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the error you need to add another object to your @graph array and it should work. The `["@graph"][1]` will then be defined. The issue was that you only had one item in your array.

```
"@graph": [ 
   { "@id": "person", "@type": "schema:Person" }, 
   {} 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `@graph` array is only 1 element in length, so `$scope.personld["@graph"][1]` doesn't exist and the command `$scope.personld["@graph"][1]["schema:familyName"] = "";` throws an error.